# How To Refer To CSS Background Image in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

What is the exact URL for me to get an image I pasted on the "Styles" directory itself? The file's name is "Header.jpg", in the directory where the default master site's css is also located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the image into the file where you want the image reference. Visual Studio will create the string for you.